# Catching "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again" error in PowerQuery to write a default in case of connection issue

Tags: excel, odbc, powerquery, m

I have a PowerQuery in an Excel workbook that tries to connect to an external DataBricks Photon DataWarehouse solution using an ODBC-driver. The query removes the data that is already in the sheet and then tries to fill the sheet with the query result data.

However, it may occur from time to time that due to issues in the VPN connection the DataWarehouse can't be reached. The PowerQuery would fail with an error saying `We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again`. I would like to be able to catch this exception in some way to still ensure the sheet is cleared, to ensure that my end user is not using any outdated data.

Any other solution that would allow me to clear the contents of a given sheet no matter if the connection to the DataWarehouse succeeds would also be fine.

The ideal solution would be something like:

```
let
    bar = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="foo"]}[Content],
    rows_removed = Table.FirstN(bar,0),
    calculated_columns_removed = Table.RemoveColumns(rows_removed,{"FR", "SA", "SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH"})
    query_result = Odbc.Query("dsn=Simba Spark", query_str),
    test_for_error = try query_result,
    recover = if test_for_error[HasError] then calculated_columns_removed else query_result

in
   recover
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried the code block below to give me an empty table in case of a connection error, but the connection errors can't be caught.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this would work

```
let bar = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="foo"]}[Content],
rows_removed = Table.FirstN(bar,0),
calculated_columns_removed = Table.RemoveColumns(rows_removed,{"FR", "SA", "SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH"})
query_result = Odbc.Query("dsn=Simba Spark", query_str),
recover = try query_result otherwise calculated_columns_removed
in recover
```